# get_post_metadata causing some meta data to fail

Tags: hooks, post-meta

I'm using the following code to extend subscription trial lengths, which requires me to modify the metadata. the problem of, other metadata is also failing, such as custom attributes and variations.

```
function filter_post_metadata( $meta_data, $object_id, $meta_key, $single ) {

    $meta_type = 'post';
    $meta_cache = wp_cache_get($object_id, $meta_type . '_meta');


    if ( !$meta_cache ) {
        $meta_cache = update_meta_cache( $meta_type, array( $object_id ) );
        $meta_cache = $meta_cache[$object_id];
    }

    if ( $meta_cache['_subscription_period_interval'] > 0 ) {
        // it's a subscription
        $meta_cache['_subscription_trial_length'][0] = $this->days_until_start;
        $meta_cache['_subscription_trial_period'][0] = 'day';
    }

    if ( !$meta_key )
        return $meta_cache;

    if ( isset($meta_cache[$meta_key]) ) {
        if ( $single )
            return maybe_unserialize( $meta_cache[$meta_key][0] );
        else
            return array_map('maybe_unserialize', $meta_cache[$meta_key]);
    }


    if ($single)
        return '';
    else
        return array();



    return $meta_data;
}
```

I'm fairly unfamiliar with this function; does anyone know why this is causing the other metadata to be dropped? I've spent a few hours looking at this and it makes no sense.